# ExtJS 4.1 Infinite Grid Scrolling doesnt work

Tags: javascript, extjs, infinite-scroll

I want to get an infinite scrolling grid with extjs4 and a c# backend... i am setting the proxy api in my controller..

My Model:

```
Ext.define('SCT.model.training.course.TrainingRequirementList', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    idProperty: 'ID',
    fields: [
        { name: 'ID', type: 'int', convert: null },
        { name: 'EmployeeName', type: 'string' },
        { name: 'Description', type: 'string' },
        { name: 'StatusText', type: 'string' },
        { name: 'Status', type: 'int' },
        { name: 'Priority', type: 'string' },
        { name: 'Date', type: 'string' },
        { name: 'Cost', type: 'string' },
        { name: 'CanApprove', type: 'bool' },
        { name: 'CanRequest', type: 'bool' },
        { name: 'ConfirmStatus', type: 'string' },
        { name: 'PlanId', type: 'int'}
    ]

});
```

My Grid:

```
{
    xtype: 'gridpanel',
    flex: 1,
    padding: '0 10 10 10',
    minHeight: 200,
    verticalScroller: {
        xtype: 'paginggridscroller'
    },
    store: {
        model: 'SCT.model.training.course.TrainingRequirementList',
        pageSize: 200,
        autoLoad: true,

        remoteSort: true,
        sorters: {
            property: 'Date',
            direction: 'DESC'
        },

        proxy: {
            type: 'direct',
            extraParams: {
                total: 50000
            },
            reader: {
                type: 'json',
                root: 'ID',
                totalProperty: 'totalCount'
            },
            simpleSortMode: true
        }
    },
    columns:
        [{
            text: Lang.Main.Employeee,
            dataIndex: 'EmployeeName',
            flex: 1,
            filterable: true
        },
        {
            text: Lang.Main.Course,
            dataIndex: 'Description',
            flex: 1,
            filterable: true
        },
        {
            text: Lang.Main.Status,
            dataIndex: 'StatusText',
            flex: 1,
            filterable: true
        },
        {
            text: Lang.Main.Priority,
            dataIndex: 'Priority',
            flex: 1
        },
        {
            text: Lang.Main.Date,
            dataIndex: 'Date',
            flex: 1
        },
        {
            text: Lang.Main.Cost,
            dataIndex: 'Cost',
            flex: 1,
            filterable: true
        },
        {
            text: Lang.Main.Actions,
            flex: 1,
            align: 'center',
            xtype: 'actioncolumn',
            width: 50,
            items: [{
                icon: 'Design/icons/cog_edit.png',
                tooltip: Lang.Main.Open,
                handler: function (grid, rowIndex, colIndex, item) {
                    this.onGridOpen(grid.getStore().getAt(rowIndex));
                }
            }]
        }],      
    selModel: { mode: 'MULTI', selType: 'checkboxmodel' },
}
```

setting proxy in controoler:

```
view.grid.getStore().setProxy({
            type: 'direct', 
            model: 'SCT.model.training.course.TrainingRequirementList', 
            api: { read: SCT.Service.Training.Plan.GetFilteredRequirements }, 
            extraParams: { total: 50000 }, 
            reader: {
                type: 'json',
                root: 'ID',
                totalProperty: 'totalCount'
            },
            simpleSortMode: true
        });
```

additional information about my view:

```
Ext.define('SCT.view.training.course.TrainingRequirements',
    {
        extend: 'Ext.panel.Panel',
        require: [ 'Ext.grid.PagingScroller', 'Ext.ux.grid.FiltersFeature'],
```

My grid is still loading all data at once (about 8000 rows...) ...
i've searched for solutions and worked through tutorials.. i still dont get it.

please help me out... i dont get it at all...

UPDATE

this is my srv request:
[image]

and the response got 3MB (about 8k datasets... ) ..??

Comment: What is your precise version of Ext? This is a feature that has been changing...

Comment: Also, are you sure that your server honors the `limit`, and `start` (or `page`) params? Are they present in the request that is sent by the browser when the store is loaded?

Comment: just updated my post... noob question: how can i see the percise version?

Comment: i guess my error is somewhere in my server script.. and i guess its actually not honoring the limits and/or pages.. you think my guess is right ?

Comment: about the version.. : i found in the sencha.cfg file the following line: framework.version=4.1.1

Comment: You could know the version you downloaded ;) or you can call `Ext.getVersion()` from your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your request dump shows that Ext effectively sends the `limit` param, so that's your server that is not handling it...

Just a piece of advice, but you should consider upgrading to last version of Ext, since buffered [grid seems to have been simplified](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/api/Ext.grid.plugin.BufferedRenderer), and that will avoid you having to rework it if you eventually upgrade.